# Insertion sort debug

Tags: java, debugging, sorting

I have tried to sort a given set of data using the insertion sort.But when i try to print the output nothing prints,the proper output is:

```
Albatross 1
mockingbird 2
vultures 3
redwoodpeckers 6
pigeons 7
crows 10
condos 12
bluejays 15
dodos 15
baldeagles 25
cardinals 40
hummung birds 88
```

---

```
String[]bn={"Cardinals","BlueJays","Albatross","Vultures","Crows","Mockingbirds","Condors","BaldEagles","Pigeons","RedHeadWoodPecker","Hummingbirds","Dodos"};
int[]bq={40,15,1,3,10,2,12,25,7,6,88,15};   
public static void SortNumericalOrdernsert (String[] bn,int[] bq){
    for(int i=1;i<bq.length;i++){
        int next=bq[i];
        String y=bn[i];
        //find all the insertion location 
        //Move all the larger elements up
        int j=i;
        while(j>0 && bq[j-1]>next){
            bn[j]=bn[j-1];
            bq[j]=bq[j-1];
               j--;
        }
        //insert the element
        bq[j]=next;
        bn[j]=y;
    }
```

can someone pls help

Comment: you should show the code where you are printing the arrays.

Comment: Where are you printing ?? i can't see any `print` statement

Comment: can you provide the code, how you are calling the SortNumericalOrdernsert method.

Comment: public static void ShowAllBirds(String[]bn,int[]bq) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   for(int a=0;a<=bn.length-1;a++){
    System.out.println(bn[a]+" : "+bq[a]);

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code and it's running properly I believe the problem is with the printing method. Please provide it so we can figure out the problem.

I have put your running code as well and there is nothing wrong with it. I believe you should provide the whole class so we can determine where the problem is. This is how I added your code and had it running with the output being as expected.

```
public class Sort {

    static String[]bn={"Cardinals","BlueJays","Albatross","Vultures","Crows","Mockingbirds","Condors","BaldEagles","Pigeons","RedHeadWoodPecker","Hummingbirds","Dodos"};
    static int[]bq={40,15,1,3,10,2,12,25,7,6,88,15};

    public static void SortNumericalOrdernsert (String[] bn,int[] bq) {
         for(int i=1;i<bq.length;i++){
             int next=bq[i];
             String y=bn[i];
            //find all the insertion location 
            //Move all the larger elements up
            int j=i;
            while(j>0 && bq[j-1]>next){
               bn[j]=bn[j-1];
               bq[j]=bq[j-1];
               j--;
            }
            //insert the element
            bq[j]=next;
            bn[j]=y;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowAllBirds(String[]bn,int[]bq) { 
        for(int a=0;a<=bn.length-1;a++) { 
            System.out.println(bn[a]+" : "+bq[a]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortNumericalOrdernsert(bn, bq);
        ShowAllBirds(bn, bq);
   }
}
```

Comment: public static void ShowAllBirds(String[]bn,int[]bq) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   for(int a=0;a<=bn.length-1;a++){
    System.out.println(bn[a]+" : "+bq[a]);

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a loop to traverse and print the individual elements of the array:

```
 for(String name: bn){ // this needs to be included at the end of your sort method AFTER the for loop
     System.out.println(name);
 }
```

Be advised; Java is pass by value and not by reference, you will have to return an array with the modified values if you intend on working with the sorted array afterwards.

Just noticed that you need both the name and its value; won't be able to use an enhanced for loop for that. You'll need to go with something along the lines of:

```
 for(int index = 0; index < bn.length; index++){
     System.out.println(bn[index] + " " + bq[index]);
 }
```

More information about for loops and arrays can be found in the Java Tutorials and Documents (just Google them).

Answer (score 0):

It works, put the arrray bn and bq as static

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static String[]bn={"Cardinals","BlueJays","Albatross","Vultures","Crows","Mockingbirds","Condors","BaldEagles","Pigeons","RedHeadWoodPecker","Hummingbirds","Dodos"};
    static int[]bq={40,15,1,3,10,2,12,25,7,6,88,15};   
    public static void SortNumericalOrdernsert (String[] bn,int[] bq){
        for(int i=1;i<bq.length;i++){
            int next=bq[i];
            String y=bn[i];
            //find all the insertion location 
            //Move all the larger elements up
            int j=i;
            while(j>0 && bq[j-1]>next){
                bn[j]=bn[j-1];
                bq[j]=bq[j-1];
                   j--;
            }
            //insert the element
            bq[j]=next;
            bn[j]=y;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SortNumericalOrdernsert(bn,bq);
        for(int i = 0; i< bn.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(bn[i] + "\t" + bq[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring static variables that don't need to be static is bad programming practice I've been told; especially when you're just learning Java and need to learn scope and encapsulation. Code works, I just don't know if its the right approach.